# Is there anyway to specify the possible types for a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, xna

I'm trying to write some code for XNA to have my own drawing modules that I can use to cache/draw static vertices/indices.

[Here's the class](http://pastebin.com/DQqDtsMY), the line in question that is giving me trouble is line 51.

```
_vertexBuffer.SetData(_vertices.ToArray());
```

It has the error: `The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T'`

It doesn't seem to like it as SetData usually expects an array of Vertices that matches the `VertexDeclaration` used in the VertexBuffers constructor, whilst my definition of the list/class says that it can be any type.

Is there anyway to specify the `<T>` as vertices?

Comment: Don't refer to an external site for relevant code. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89309

Comment: If `SetData` expects a specific type, why make your class generic? Can't you use that specific type (or its base) in place of `T`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did try that but I still got the same error, Even if I do `where T : IVertexType` it doesn't work as `SetData` expects a `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). Whatever the `VertexBuffer` type is, it has this on that method:

```
void SetData<T>(...) where T : struct
```

This is what is causing your error.

In fact, MSDN says that this is the method signature:

```
public void SetData<T> (
     T[] data
) where T : ValueType
```

Which is essentially the same.

So, to fix this, you'll have to pass in an array of items that are value types, not reference types. That is, your instantiation of `DrawModule<T>` must be `DrawModule<ValueTypeHere>`.

Comment: Quite strange that [the MSDN doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198836.aspx) didn't get the constraint syntax right in the C# tab of the "code box". In other pages they do write `where T : struct` which is the correct way in C#.

Comment: Indeed. The compiler wouldn't allow the use of `ValueType` I wouldn't think (I don't recall that being legal).

Comment: Here's another [doc page from the same assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434115.aspx), and they use `T : struct` there!

Comment: Very weird. Crazy documentation generators :P